# Changing themes and environment variables :: 14.04 lts

Tags: command-line, unity, themes, gtk, style

Hey i'm having problems trying to find an editor for the theme color options, particularly pertaining to the field color and text color for general windows.

I downloaded the new version of the GTK-theme-editor, now just called "Theme Configuration". This however just alters the title bar and menu texts, not the main fields of the windows.

I dont understand why there was a removal of basic window options and themes from the operating system.

Also Myunity does not work with the commands posted at the community page. I get a "E: unable to locate package" every time the apt-get is ran for it...

I will admit that i am a fairly new user to lixux, and have been looking for information and not finding anything relevant or current for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Install GNOME Color Chooser. This provides a variety of options.

`sudo apt-get install gnome-color-chooser`

> This however just alters the title bar and menu texts, not the main
>   fields of the windows.

This tool allows you to change the color of the text boxes and panels and such. Hope this is what you are looking for.